# Finding rows containing more than two sequential TRUE logical values

Tags: r

My dataframe is as follows:

```
  structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), A = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
 FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), B = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
 FALSE, FALSE), C = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 
  D = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), E = c(TRUE, 
 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B",    
 "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))


> Df
  ID     A     B     C     D    E   
 1  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 2  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE
 3  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 5  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
 6  6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

I would like to find rows containing at least two sequential TRUE values. It will return value "1" in a new column "User". The other rows will return value "0" in the column "User":

```
 > Df1
   ID     A     B     C     D    E User
 1  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
 2  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE    0
 3  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
 4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
 5  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE    1
 6  6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE    1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `rle`:

```
Df$User <- apply(Df[, -1], 1, function(x)
    as.numeric(any(rle(x)$lengths >= 2 & rle(x)$values)))
Df;
#ID     A     B     C     D    E User
#1  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#2  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE    0
#3  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#4  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#5  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE    1
#6  6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE    1
```

Explanation: `rle` calculates the lengths and values of consecutive equal values in every row of `Df`. We then flag those rows that have `>=2` equal values that are `TRUE`.

---

### Sample data

```
Df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), A = c(FALSE, FALSE,
 FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), B = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
 FALSE, FALSE), C = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  D = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), E = c(TRUE,
 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B",
 "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[melt(df, id.var = "ID")[, .(V1 = rleid(value)* value, value = value), 
   .(ID)][(value),  .(User = as.integer(.N > 1)),.(ID, V1)], User := User, on = .(ID)]
df
#   ID     A     B     C     D    E User
#1:  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#2:  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE    0
#3:  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#4:  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE    0
#5:  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE    1
#6:  6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE    1
```